# Getting Login button error during run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When i run my code i am getting login button  error during run time.. why i am getting a simple button on clicking it should validate but for that design also i am getting error

```
ASP.userinterface_login_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnLogin_Click' and no extension method 'btnLogin_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.userinterface_login_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and here is my design

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="btnLogin_Click"   />
```

Comment: Have you defined the `btnLogin_Click` method in your code behind file? This happens when you declaratively attach the event in aspx page but do not define it in code behind(.aspx.cs) file.

Comment: @RahulSingh yes by clicking the Log in event it takes me the code behind(.cs) where i have defined what action that button need to perform

Comment: Can you post your code behind code or just the `btnLogin_Click` method?